# Howto recursively remove directory in Meteor?

Tags: meteor, directory, rm

What is the best way for recursively directory removing with Meteor ?

Comment: What do you mean directory? If you are talking about the filesystem on the server, you'd use node.js' built-in fs module.

Comment: fs.rmdir can only remove empty directory, I'm talking about utility like `rimraf`. Or maybe CollectionFS have an apropriate method for this ?

Answer (score 1):

Use an existing [npm](https://github.com/meteorhacks/npm) module like [rimraf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rimraf). Here's how you do it starting from an empty project:

```
$ meteor add meteorhacks:npm meteorhacks:async
$ meteor
```

Once meteor starts, stop it and edit `packages.json` to look like:

```
{
  "rimraf": "2.2.8"
}
```

Then add something like this in a file under your `server` directory:

```js
var removeDirectory = Async.wrap(Meteor.npmRequire('rimraf'));

Meteor.startup(function() {
  removeDirectory('/dir/to/remove');
});
```

Where `/dir/to/remove` is, you guessed it, the directory you want to recursively remove.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I do it (in CoffeeScript):

```
fs = requre('fs')

_emptyDirectory = (target) ->
  _rm(path.join(target, p)) for p in fs.readdirSync(target)

_rm = (target) ->
  if fs.statSync(target).isDirectory()
    _emptyDirectory(target)
    fs.rmdirSync(target)
  else
    fs.unlinkSync(target)
```